# Fill data of sub report with master report field value

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I'm using *iReport 5.0*.

My *subReport* is not receiving the list if objects that it needs to show. How do i give this list from main report to *subReport*, without using DB connection.

To explain situation:
-I have a List of Questions, each question have a list of Answers and a percentage of correct ones.

So on *Java*:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollection2 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listOfQuestions);
JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Report/SurveyGeneralReport.jasper"),
                new HashMap<String,Object>(), beanCollection2) ;
```

On my SurveyGeneralReport.jrxml I have:

```xml
<parameter name="ROOT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["example\\resources\\Report\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROOT_DIR} + "SubReport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
.
.
.
.
<detail>
        <band height="68" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bdd12e8b-f8f6-4aea-b2ff-d17255fb6559" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{question}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="01c7d5a6-c89d-4c56-a14e-18ac5eeb1a71" x="100" y="20" width="415" height="48"/>
                <subreportParameter name="answers">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{answers}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "AnswersubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

On the AnswersubReport.jrxml:

```
<parameter name="answers" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<field name="answerValue" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="answerPercentage" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

So how do i tell subreport to iterate over answers parameter?

My exception is:

```
15:12:21,821 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/admin/round].[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() para servlet Faces Servlet lanzó excepción: java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRPrintBand.addOffsetElements(JRPrintBand.java:101) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.addSubElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:623) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.fillElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:600) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:406) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2023) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:265) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624) [:4.1.3]
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:605) [:4.1.3]
```

If i can be more clear please ask me for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://youtu.be/dgLjnnnvDmk?t=16m33s)

What i did was a data source expression,

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{answers})
```